# How to implement a Boolean expression to find duplicates in a linked list?

Tags: c++, duplicates, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm having trouble with my function that is suppose to return true if the linked list has duplicates of a certain value passed into the function

Note: This is a singly linked list.

Comment: Are you satisfied that your "bool object::operator== ()" is working?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing ... one other issue I noticed was that your code did not exit until finding a 2nd duplicate (counter > 1).   This is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You might be calling `->getNext` on a `NULL` item. You want your `while` to check the following solution:

```
while (nodeptr != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Except that the condition of the while statement should look like

```
while ( nodeptr != NULL )
```

I do not see other problems with the function.

Nevertheless I would define it the following way

```
bool List<Object>::hasDuplicates( const Object& data ) const
{
    // Determine whether the data element is duplicated

    size_type counter = 0;

    for ( ListNode<Object>* nodeptr = head; counter < 2 && nodeptr; nodeptr = nodeptr->getNext() )
    {   
        if ( nodeptr->getElement() == data ) ++counter;
    }

    return counter == 2;
}
```

Another way to write the loop is to use the break statement. For example

```
bool List<Object>::hasDuplicates( const Object& data ) const
{
    // Determine whether the data element is duplicated

    size_type counter = 0;

    for ( ListNode<Object>* nodeptr = head; nodeptr; nodeptr = nodeptr->getNext() )
    {   
        if ( nodeptr->getElement() == data && ++counter == 2 ) break;
    }

    return counter == 2;
}
```

Comment: You will be doing `counter < 2` check on each iteration, while it is only needed when `counter` is incremented.

Comment: @Mikhail  It is not important. The more important that the code is more readable and clear. Of course you could use the break statement but I do not like break statements in such simple loops.

Comment: @Mikhail Specially for you I included also one loop implementation.:)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this :) And for me this version looks more readable, since you are not doing anything unusual in the loop header. I still wouldn't accept this `nodeptr->getElement() == data && ++counter == 2` part on code review, though it's perfectly legal. I see no reason in such compactification.

Answer (score 0):

A recursion enthusiast might suggest:

```
// returns true when data contained in list more than once
// else returns false
template <class Object>
bool List<Object>::hasDuplicates( const Object& data ) const
{
   ListNode<Object>* head = front();  // gotta start some where

   int counter = 0;
   if(head != nullptr)  // list not empty?
      head->hasDuplicates (data, counter); // recursive search

  return (count > 1);
}

// recursive - counter incremented when data matches element
//             aborts further search when counter > 1
template <class Object>
void List<Object>::hasDuplicates( const Object& data, int& counter ) const
{
   counter += (data == getElement()) ? 1 : 0; // is node dup 

   if(counter > 1) return;           // found 2nd, abort search

   if(nullptr == getNext()) return; // abort search, no more elements

   getNext()->hasDuplicates(data, counter);  // tail recursion
}
```

Not compiled .. for illustration purposes only.

g++ with -O3 has impressed me with its handling of tail recursion